# Using environment variables in camel.xml to configure endpoints

Tags: variables, configuration, apache-camel, environment, endpoint

I have a cxf endpoint configuration in my camel.xml like this:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="callbackInbound"
      serviceClass="ch.axpo.emis.v1.timeseriesservice.Callback"
      wsdlURL="wsdl/timeseries.wsdl" endpointName="tss:CallbackPort"
      address="http://somehost.com:9090/CallbackService" serviceName="tss:CallbackService"/>
```

In one of my routes I call this endpoint like this:

```
.to("cxf:bean:callbackInbound?dataFormat=PAYLOAD")
```

So, now instead of having a fix address (http://somehost.com:9090/CallbackService) I want to be able to configure the address for different environments (DEV, TEST, PROD, ...) using system variables. This is because I use JBoss 7 as runtime environment for camel and there is a quite simple way to add system variables with JBoss. 
Is there a way to do that? Or is there a better way to configure cxf endpoints in different environments?

Thanks,
Sven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [properties components](https://camel.apache.org/properties) and define the cxfEndpoint like this

```
System.setProperty("environment", "junit");

<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="routerEndpoint" address="{{router.address}}"
serviceClass="org.apache.camel.component.cxf.HelloService"/>
```

You can define the property file just like this

```
router.address={{{{environment}}.router.address}}

# LOCAL SERVER
junit.router.address=junit

# LOCAL SERVER
local.router.address=local

# TEST
test.router.address=test

# PROD
prod.router.address=prod
```